# How to disable NetBios in C# in SQL Server communication

Tags: c#, sql-server, netbios

I have a problem with my connection to SQL Server in a C# application.
After `Open()`, I see a NetBios request, but the server does not respond and after a few seconds, the connection is closed:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/mut3srWNxKXRUYDcA

After 2-3 attempts, the connection is established, but it takes around 10 seconds.

On the client side, we don’t use SQL NetBios but instead pipe connection type only - something like that (with Windows authentications):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = “SERVER=1.2.3.4;DATABASE=dbName;POOLING=true;Connect Timeout=30;Integrated Security=SSPI”;
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ColumnName] FROM TableName", conn);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(dt);

    conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();
}
```

How to enable respond for this NBSTAT packets on server side or disable it on application side in C# code (but not disabled NetBios itself).

Comment: MSSQL Auth doesn't work this way. However you might want to try some variantion on this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66022

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the same problem I get.